# Earth Engine Token expired or revoked

Tags: google-earth-engine, qgis-plugins

Have recently found that the QGIS GEE data catalogue will not load.
have uninstalled and reinstalled - it still doesn't load.

it gives the error:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})

I've found that I must reauthenticate earth engine.

---

so far, I've been able to install miniconda and can access conda from the powershell command line. I've also installed gcloud

"earthengine authenticate" results in:
File "C:\Users\TimMI\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\oauth.py", line 294, in _load_app_default_credentials raise Exception('gcloud command not found. ' + tip) from e
Exception: gcloud command not found. Please ensure that gcloud is installed.

But Gcloud is installed, has its path set, is initialised, and is accessible from the powershell command line.

---

can anyone advise how to Authenticate/reauthenticate Earthengine on a local machine?

Comment: `File "C:\Users\TimMI\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\oauth.py"` looks to me like you've installed stuff in your `base` miniconda environment. You should generally not install things to `base` but to a separate environment.  Did you install QGIS via conda or are you attempting to mix a non-conda QGIS install with conda packages?

Comment: QGIS is installed via Osgeo/the standard downloadable install package for windows. re the install locations - I've run whatever install packages or scripts I've been able to locate, and paths are whatever was determined by the install package designers (Google in this case I think)

Comment: OsGEO QGIS doesn't use conda installed packages.

Comment: k, that seems to be correct. online instructions state that I have to install GEE via conda or pip, then run "earthengine authenticate" to reset the QGIS GEE authentication, and GEE will then work in QGIS again. if this is not correct, please tell me how I can reset the authentication token from within QGIS. reinstalling the plugin and upgrading QGIS have not worked

Comment: I wish I could simply delete all GEE config files and install a completely fresh version - forcing it to complete a new activation. I have found no instructions on how to achieve this.